# SSK 2.5" external HDD power source?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power

I'm trying to access an old SSK "Mobile Storage Solution" external hard disk drive, but it appears to have been separated from whatever power source or special cable is uses. It will not work with a simple plug in to a USP port, although the light goes on. The unit has a DC plug-in port, but there is no indication of the correct power level. Any information on this device or guidance how to troubleshoot without damaging it?

Amazon has what looks like the exact same device for sale as: [High Quality SSK 2.5" USB 2.0 IDE External Hard Drive HDD Enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0102P3D2O)

Comment: From what I can tell those never come with the optional AC adapter; and USB should be enough to power it.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1) You can take the disk drive out and use a different USB<->IDE adapter. 2) Can you hear the disk spin up when you connect it to a PC USB port?

Answer (score 1):

The enclosure says for 2.5" IDE drives. The 2.5" formfactor of HDDs is intended for use in laptops, where the major peripheral power is 5V DC. Therefore it is very likely that the external power source is 5V, and much less likely to be 12V.

You can do two things. First connect the enclosure to 5V wall AC adaper (or into anything 5V) with at least 2A rating, and see if will start working. Usually lower voltage will not harm devices designed for 12V.

Second, open the enclosure and find the DC power requirements written on the drive itself. If it lists only "DC+5V 0.7A" or something, it is definitely for a 5V external supply.

For more confidence, check if the USB bridge board has any additional small chips surrounded by sizeable inductors and sizeable caps in the vicinity of power jack. There should be something like a small 5V-3.3V LDO to power the main IC, but not any switching power supply for 12V-5V DC-DC conversion.

Also, this kind of old devices usually came with a special Y-split cable, to use two USB ports as a beefed-up power supply. Keep in mind that the spin-up phase of old IDE HDDs might need about 1.8-2A of current for first several seconds, and if the VBUS voltage droops during the start, the electronics might fail to initialize the drive properly, and there will be no USB connection.